# ES6 class access parent object in a local scope

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6, browserify

What is the best way to access the parent object where my classes are defined in it? The followed code is wrapped by Browserify and not accessible in the global scope. I declare a variable to the `Game` object which contains all my vars and classes. If a class need to access the `Game` object, I need to do `this.game`, but is there a better way to do it?

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.game = Game;
        this.name = "Foo";
        this.value = 100;
    }

    accessGame() {
        return console.log(this.game);
    }
}

var Game = {};
Game.Foo = new Foo();
```

I'm new to ES6 classes, sorry if this is a dumb question, thanks.

Comment: `this.game` is how you access instance data of an object from within a method.   I'm not sure what else you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tbh it's hard to say the best way without knowing exactly what you want to do with your class.

Without knowing what you're planning on doing, however, a simple way to be able to access the game instance from within the class is to pass it as an argument upon initialization.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(game) {
        this.game = game;
        this.name = "Foo";
        this.value = 100;
    }

    accessGame() {
        return console.log(this.game);
    }
}

var Game = {};
Game.Foo = new Foo(Game);

Game.Foo.accessGame()
```

But note that there's tons of different ways you can accomplish this and the best way depends on exactly what 'foo' is in relation to your Game.

Comment: Just sharing the obvious but `return console.log(this.game)` _logs_ `this.game` but _returns_ `undefined`

Comment: I was looking for a better way and didn't know if there was one, but it looks like there is not. I will stay with my solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can also store a Master class 'loader' or 'app'
and add a getter based on static reference.

example

```
class _coreLoader {
    constructor () {
    };

    getClass(className){
        switch (className) {
            case 'Scene_Boot'      : return Scene_Boot      ; break;
            case 'Scene_IntroVideo': return Scene_IntroVideo; break;
            case 'Scene_Menu'      : return Scene_Menu      ; break;
        };
    };
```

so example here `const myclass = $Loader.getClass('Scene_Boot')` will work.
But you need store manually all reference.